# Animate UIImageView by Set Distance

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I am trying to move an image view forward by a set distance but can't seem to get it working.  My turnRight and turnLeft methods work fine.  I'm just having issues with the moveForward method. Here is what I'm trying:

```
- (IBAction)moveForward:(id)sender
{
    if (turtle.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationRight)
    {
        turtle.frame = CGRectMake(turtle.frame.origin.x + 10, turtle.frame.origin.y, 75, 75);
    }
    else if (turtle.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationLeft)
    {
        turtle.frame = CGRectMake(turtle.frame.origin.x - 10, turtle.frame.origin.y, 75, 75);
    }
    else if (turtle.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationUp)
    {
        turtle.frame = CGRectMake(turtle.frame.origin.x, turtle.frame.origin.y + 10, 75, 75);
    }
    else if (turtle.image.imageOrientation == UIImageOrientationDown)
    {
        turtle.frame = CGRectMake(turtle.frame.origin.x, turtle.frame.origin.y - 10, 75, 75);
    }
}

- (IBAction)turnRight:(id)sender
{   
    UIImage *newImage;

    switch (turtle.image.imageOrientation)
    {
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[turtle.image CGImage] scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
            turtle.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[turtle.image CGImage]scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
            turtle.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[turtle.image CGImage] scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];
            turtle.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[turtle.image CGImage]scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
            turtle.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    turtle.image = newImage;
}

- (IBAction)turnLeft:(id)sender
{
    UIImage *newImage;

    switch (turtle.image.imageOrientation)
    {
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[turtle.image CGImage] scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationLeft];
            turtle.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[turtle.image CGImage]scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationDown];
            turtle.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[turtle.image CGImage] scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationRight];
            turtle.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            newImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[turtle.image CGImage]scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
            turtle.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    turtle.image = newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 things to consider here.

1) Make sure you are making UI changes on the main thread.
2) Use UIView's animation methods

```
- (IBAction)moveForward:(id)sender
{
    CGRect frame = turtle.frame;
    switch (turtle.image.imageOrientation)
    {
        case UIImageOrientationUp:
            frame.origin.y + 10; 
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationLeft:
            frame.origin.x - 10;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationDown:
            frame.origin.y + 10;
            break;
        case UIImageOrientationRight:
            frame.origin.x + 10;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1.0 // The duration in seconds for the animation to complete.
                 animations:^{
                     turtle.frame = frame;
                 }];
}
```

Comment: It is using the main thread.  I checked by adding if ([NSThread isMainThread])
    {
        NSLog(@"Main Thread");
    }

Comment: Something else is causing your problem. You can confirm that `moveForward:` is being called, right?

Comment: Well, when I press the button that uses it, it print the NSLog I put in to determine if it's using the main thread.

Comment: Is the turtle object equal to `nil`?

Comment: It doesn't appear to be.  I added  if (turtle == nil)
    {
        NSLog(@"Turtle object is nil");
    }
to check.

Comment: Add this line just before the `[UIView ...]` call. `NSLog(@"turtle frame: %@", NSStringFromCGRect(turtle.frame));` and tap the button a few times. Paste the logs here so I can see them.

Comment: It is returning the original location of the turtle image view.

Comment: It is returning the same location over and over?

Comment: Every time I press the button associated with that method.

Comment: You need to make sure the code goes into one of the cases of the switch statement. Put a break point in each case and see that the code enters one of them. Make sure turtle.image is not nil either.

Comment: It hits the first case when in the initial position. It hits the second case when I rotate it and it's facing up. It hits the third case when it's rotated and facing left, and it hits the last fourth case when it's rotated and facing down.

Comment: turtle.image is not nil

Comment: I've changed it back to my original if statements and the position changes but not the right direction. If the turtle is in the original position (facing right) it moves down, if it's rotated to face up it moves left, rotated to face left it moves up, and rotated to face down, it moves right.